# Get number of days/months between multiple dates for IDs in a data frame?

Tags: r, date

For each unique ID, I am trying to determine the number of days (or months, preferably) between the first occurrence and the most recent occurrence.

Example:

```
        date id
1 2011-02-09  A
2 2011-02-09  B
3 2011-02-09  C
4 2011-03-10  A
5 2011-03-10  D
6 2011-01-19  B
7 2011-02-02  C
8 2011-02-02  D
```

Output:

```
days id
  29 A
  21 B
   7 C
  36 D
```

This is a simple example of my real data. The data set spans multiple years and each ID may have dozens of associated dates. Therefore, **the result for each ID would be the difference between the min and max dates for each ID.**

Code I used to create sample:

```
date <- c("2011-02-09","2011-02-09","2011-02-09","2011-03-10","2011-03-10","2011-01-19","2011-02-02","2011-02-02")
id <- c("A","B","C","A","D","B","C","D")
df <-data.frame(date,id)
```

Thanks!

### Edit

Forgot to include I used as.Date to convert the date column, since it defaults to factors in a data frame.

Comment: In base R you could try: `tapply(df$date,df$id,function(x) diff(range(x)))`

Comment: @nicola, I would post this as an answer as it is the best base R solution IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(days=c(max(date)-min(date)))
#    id days
#1  A   29
#2  B   21
#3  C    7
#4  D   36
```

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(date~id, df, function(x) max(x)-min(x))
#   id date
#1  A  29 
#2  B  21 
#3  C   7 
#4  D  36
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(15014, 15014, 15014, 15043, 
 15043, 14993, 15007, 15007), class = "Date"), id = c("A", "B", 
"C", "A", "D", "B", "C", "D")), .Names = c("date", "id"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Wow that was a blazing fast reply. I'll give it a shot and reply back. Thanks!

Comment: You probably should to convert to `Date` class somewhere here, no?

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I did converted to `Date` assuming that the the OP created the example and forgot about it.

Answer (score 3):

Or (obligatory) `data.table` solution for completeness

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(days = diff(range(as.Date(date)))), by = id]
#    id    days
# 1:  A 29 days
# 2:  B 21 days
# 3:  C  7 days
# 4:  D 36 days
```

Or possible base R implementation (though `tapply` would be the best option here)

```
sapply(split(df$date, df$id), function(x) diff(range(as.Date(x))))
##  A  B  C  D 
## 29 21  7 36
```

Or

```
do.call(rbind, list(by(df, df$id, function(x) diff(range(as.Date(x[, "date"]))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I expand the comment I made to propose another `base` R solution:

```
 tapply(df$date,df$id,function(x) diff(range(x)))
```

As noted in the comments, if `df$date` is not a `Date` object, the above line changes in:

```
 tapply(as.Date(df$date),df$id,function(x) diff(range(x)))
```